# development of electric field in a MOS capacitor

Tags: mosfet

How can we explain the development of electric field in a MOS capacitor(not connected to any circuit)?

To be more precise,I want to know what was the driving force for the accumulation of positive charges at the interface between the metal and insulator and negative charge in the bulk of semiconductor near the interface of semiconductor and insulator.

Is it because of the difference in concentration of electron in metal and semiconductor that electron flow from metal *through insulator* to semiconductor that the charge is developed?

Answer (score 2):

Potential difference is the integral of the electric field along a path between two points:

$$V_{ba} = -\int_a^b \vec{E}\cdot\rm{d}\vec{\mathcal{l}}$$

So whenever you see a potential difference between two points, that's really just a simplified way of looking at the fact that there's an electric field between them.

You shouldn't expect insulators to prevent electric fields. In fact, conductors tend to "block" electric fields, since they allow charge to move around to counteract whatever fields are imposed on them. Dielectrics tend to have minimal effect on static fields.

Comment: I have not connected any battery to it,how did the potential difference develop then? Was it due to flow of some electrons from metal to semiconductor through insulator because of the concentration gradient between them?

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more clear what you're asking about. Is the FET just sitting on your behchtop? Is it connected in some circuit but the power is off? Is it connected in a circuit but powered by something other than a battery? We can't read your mind, so you have to tell us what you are thinking.